# Where does pip evaluate the installation directory?

Tags: python, pip

I embedded Python 3.6 in my application, and it's directory structure is slightly different to an official Python installation:

```
- foo.exe   <-- embeds Python, but acts as a Python interpreter
- deps/
  |--- DLLs
  |--- Lib
  |--- Scripts
```

`foo.exe` can be used like a `python.exe`, so `foo.exe get-pip.py` works. The problem is, the files get installed next to `foo.exe`, and not in the deps directory. Like here:

```
- foo.exe
- Scripts/      <--- wrong level
  |--- pip3.6.exe
- Lib/      <--- wrong level
  |--- site-packages
       |--- pip
       |--- setuptools
- deps/
  |--- DLLs
  |--- Lib
  |--- Scripts
```

Here are some values I set during the initialization of Python via [Py_SetProgramName](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#c.Py_SetProgramName) and [Py_SetPath](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#c.Py_SetPath)

```
sys.executable: C:\app\foo.exe
sys.path: 'C:\app\deps\DLLs';'C:\app\deps\Lib';''
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Or does anyone know where I can lookup which path component is used to evaluate the installation directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path you are looking for is defined in [sys.prefix](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.prefix).
If it's empty, set your configuration up in a way that it points to `deps`.

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#c.Py_SetPath), this is the statement you maybe missed:

> This also causes sys.executable to be set to the program full path
>   (see Py_GetProgramFullPath()) and for sys.prefix and sys.exec_prefix
>   to be empty. **It is up to the caller to modify these if required after**
>   **calling Py_Initialize()**.